# where should I modify the given shell script?

Tags: shell-script

This is my input:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Example of menu programs
clear
echo "*******************"
echo "1.Date"
echo "2.List of users"
echo "3.Open a file"
echo "4.delete a file"
echo "5.Exit"

echo "Enter a choice[1-5] :"
read choice
case $choice in
1) echo "Today date is : `date`";;
2) who ;;
3) `touch file`;;
4) `rm -rf kk`;;
5) exit ;;
*) echo "choice wrong. try again";;
esac
```

This is my output:

```
*******************
1.Date
2.List of users
3.Open a file
4.delete a file
5.Exit
Enter a choice[1-5] :
1
Today date is : Sun Jul 19 08:07:41 PDT 2015
```

But I'm not expecting this output.

What I am expecting:

```
*******************
1.Date
2.List of users
3.Open a file
4.delete a file
5.Exit
Enter a choice[1-5] :
1
Today date is : Sun Jul 19 08:07:41 PDT 2015

*******************

1.Date
2.List of users
3.Open a file
4.delete a file
5.Exit
Enter a choice[1-5] :
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to add a loop to repeat the menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Example of menu programs
while true;
do
    echo "*******************"
    echo "1.Date"
    echo "2.List of users"
    echo "3.Open a file"
    echo "4.delete a file"
    echo "5.Exit"
    echo "*******************"

    echo "Enter a choice[1-5] :"
    read choice
    case $choice in
        1) echo "Today date is : `date`";;
        2) who ;;
        3) `touch file`;;
        4) `rm -rf kk`;;
        5) break ;;
        *) echo "Wrong choice. Please try again";;
    esac
done
```

For your reference: [Unix - Shell Loop Control](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-loop-control.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Put it in a loop:

```
while true; do
    echo "*******************"
    echo "1.Date"
    echo "2.List of users"
    echo "3.Open a file"
    echo "4.delete a file"
    echo "5.Exit"

    echo "Enter a choice[1-5] :"
    read choice
    case $choice in
    1) echo "Today date is : `date`";;
    2) who ;;
    3) `touch file`;;
    4) `rm -rf kk`;;
    5) break ;;
    *) echo "choice wrong. try again";;
    esac
done
```

or put your script inside the loop

```
while true; do
     menu.sh
done
```

Comment: may be replace exit by break ?